# regex for capturing between quotes including skipped quotes

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I need to use regex for capturing whatever between the text tag quotes in python string after reading it from a file.
I tried the below regex and it worked fine except for handling the escaped backslashes before the quotation at the end of the captured string

```
\"text\":\"(.*?)(?<!\\)\"
```

example string:

```
{"id":"2","text":"@mmm .\uD83D\uDE02\\"},{"id":"3","text":"a\"bs"},
```

it should return

```
match1:@mmm .\uD83D\uDE02\\

match2:a\"bs
```

but because of the regex is not able to properly handle the escaped backslash at the end of match1, it is failing.
can you please advice on how to handle that?

Comment: Something like [this](https://regex101.com/r/BMYvWy/1)?

Comment: Thanks@JvdV, but I don't need to include the brackets in my expression , I ended up using the belew regex `"text":"((?:.*?[^\\])(?:\\\\)*)"`